# Questionable code in GHC.Prim

Tags: haskell, ghc

I came across the following code in [GHC.Prim](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.2/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.2.0.0/src/GHC-Prim.html#expFloat#):

```
...

negateFloat# :: Float# -> Float#
negateFloat# = let x = x in x

-- |Truncates a @Float#@ value to the nearest @Int#@.
--     Results are undefined if the truncation if truncation yields
--     a value outside the range of @Int#@.

float2Int# :: Float# -> Int#
float2Int# = let x = x in x

expFloat# :: Float# -> Float#
expFloat# = let x = x in x

logFloat# :: Float# -> Float#
logFloat# = let x = x in x

...
```

In particular:

1. `float2Int#` shouldn't even type check
2. None of the functions take an argument and hence seem to be malformed
3. None of the functions apply the mathematical operation they claim to
4. All of the functions are "infinitely recursive": `let x = x`

I know the extension is called "MagicHash", but it can't be *that* magical. What gives?

(I guess I should add the disclaimer that I have no idea what `-XMagicHash` *actually* does, I just assumed it allowed the `#` syntax, and nothing more.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The clue is at the top of the module:

```
{-
This is a generated file (generated by genprimopcode).
It is not code to actually be used. Its only purpose is to be
consumed by haddock.
-}
```

Incidentally, `let x = x in x` is equivalent to `undefined`, and is valid for any data type; `x` isn't constrained by being defined in any way other than self-referentially, so can be any type.

These functions are "primitive" meaning operations so basic they're not defined in Haskell code, and quite possibly just translated directly to machine instructions.

Comment: So I've found code that *uses* this function, in a seemingly reasonable way [meta-repa](https://github.com/jankner/meta-repa/blob/master/FOASTyped.hs). I can't be *just* for documentation, can it? Is there another version of these functions defined elsewhere?

Comment: @Eric Oh yes, but not here. They're primitive, meaning defined other than by Haskell code.

Comment: @Eric: That code uses the GHC built-ins.

Comment: Point taken about my questions #1, #2, and #4. That's obvious in hindsight.

Comment: In effect it's inlined as your code is compiled / imported into the runtume / written in a lower level language.

Comment: So is there any place I can see where it is actually defined? I don't expect any surprises, but it seems like I should be able to look if I want.

Comment: Is there any reason for using `let x = x in x` over `undefined`? The latter is shorter and makes it more immediately clear that nothing is happening.

Comment: `undefined` is defined in the prelude, which imports the primitives, not the other way round. Actually, `undefined` throws an error. `undefined =  error "Prelude.undefined"` and `error s = throw (ErrorCall s)`, whereas `let x = x in x` is just a loop.

Comment: So Prelude is not in scope in GHC.Exts?

Comment: Er... dunno, but I'm sure it's not in scope in `GHC.Prim`, which is the module linked to.

Comment: Oops, didn't realize it linked me to a different module! Thanks!

Comment: The primitive operations don't exist in Haskell, but they do exist in cmm (C minus minus) : https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/rts/PrimOps.cmm.